# Не передаются все значения из гугл таблицы

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, gspread

Код ниже позволяет получать информацию из таблицы, но только первое встретившееся значение, то есть если в первой и в третье строках одно и то же наименование, в выводе будет только содержание первой строки. Как передать все строки, совпавшие с запросом?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def search(message):
    try:
        search_cell = wks.find(message.text)
        list = wks.row_values(search_cell.row)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "Наименование: %s\nГоден до: %s\nКоличество: %s" % (list[0], list[2], list[3]))
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'В таблице {message.text} не найдено!')
```